# Receive data continuously from socket react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets

I'm currently using this code for receiving data from sockets
Code:

```
 socket.on('send_image', (message) => {
        setImage(message.image)
        console.log(message)
      })
```

the server sends data(images from camera) continuously. how to receive it without refreshing? i tried one method that requests data every milliseconds. i don't know whether it is a good way or not

Request every milliseconds code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {

      socket.on('send_image', (message) => {
        setImage(message.image)
        console.log(message)
      })
      
    }, 10);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
```

is there any other way to continuously receive data from sockets?

Comment: setInterval would make sense if you were sending data or requesting it. But it's not the case. With a socket, you don't request it but receive it in a passive way

Comment: @EstusFlask i only receive data and server sends new image continuously i need to receive it immediately

Comment: Immediately how? You receive it when it's sent via socket, not earlier, not later

Comment: @EstusFlask I only receive new data when refreshing the page

Comment: It's done the way the answer shows, not the way you did it. If you need to skip some data if it's sent too often, you can throttle handler function, or even better fix it on server side because it wastes bandwidth otherwise. If you really want to update 100 times a second, you may want to update DOM directly instead of updating the whole component, this will make the performance much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the local state as soon as a `send_image` message is received, just register the handler in your `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (message) => {
    setImage(message.image);
    console.log(message);
  };
  socket.on("send_image", handler);
  return () => socket.off("send_image", handler); // assuming `.off` deregisters a callback
}, []);
```

Comment: I'm most probably receive image data every milliseconds can it able to handle this?

Comment: This will be the fastest way to process those messages in a browser. Every millisecond, though? Are you sure you'd be receiving 1000 images per second? What will you do with those images? Your display is likely to be 60 Hz or maybe 144 Hz (17 msec or 7 msec per frame, respectively), so you'd lose most (94% or 86%) of those 1000 images per second anyway.

Comment: @AKX Technically the fastest way is to update DOM. Updating a state 100+ times a second is a sure way to kill the performance in React (probably in web in general too but that's another thing)

Comment: @EstusFlask Technically the fastest way is to not do anything with the data received. We don't know if OP will use it in the DOM at all (be it via React or direct DOM manipulation) at this point. For all we know, they'll put it in an UInt8Array and find all red pixels via WASM.

Comment: @AKX server emitting images from camera so i am gonna receive a lot of images that's why im asking now i understand my display can't handle that much images